# Google Drive File Stream keeps enabling it's Finder extension

Tags: finder, google-apps

I do not want any Finder extensions and turn I them off in System Preferences. After quitting and reopening Google Drive File Stream, its Finder extension always turns back on.

What can I do to ensure it remains turned off?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Google Drive Stream is defaulted to automatically start at login within the [Google Drive Stream preferences](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7644837?hl=en).

There are two places it can be set - system (host) wide, or user only.  The locations are as follows:

- System Wide: `/Library/Preferences/com.google.drivefs.settings`
- User Only:  `~/Library/Preferences/com.google.drivefs.settings`

Check to see settings by using the `defaults` command to get the `AutoStartOnLogin` setting.  For example, to see the setting system wide issue the command:

```
$ sudo defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.google.drivefs.settings AutoStartOnLogin
```

Do this for both locations by changing the path to the `.settings` file as described above.

If either come back "true", you've found the cause.  Next, write a new value to turn it off.  System wide example:

```
$ sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.google.drivefs.settings AutoStartOnLogin -bool false
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with the Google Drive extension. There’s not much that can be done.

You can try:

- Rebooting your Mac
- Updating Google Drive
- Seeing if the launch of a specific app named it enable

If that doesn’t work the best option would be to submit a Google bug report.

You can see Google contact methods [here.](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/4431192?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)